# C# referenced VB UserControl not found

Tags: .net, vb.net, c#-4.0

I have a C# project where i reference another project, which is written using VB. I can use all classes and forms from the referenced project, except 2. One class is `UserControl` and another one is `Module`, while all other are simple Win Forms. I get `"A type or namespace name 'XXX' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"`.
I already checked .NET versions (all projects have the same one - .NET 4 (not Client Profile)), tried changing platform target and other stuff. Nothing helps.
Anybody has any ideas?

Comment: You have ensured that the project built successfully, right?

Comment: Yes, the project i am referencing has built successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Check the visibility of `UserControl` and `Module`. Maybe you forgot the `Public` modifier, because the default visibility of a class or module is `protected` (`Friend`in VB.Net)

```
Class [Module] ' NOT visible to other assemblies
    ' ...
End Class

Public Class [Module] ' Visible to other assemblies
     ' ...
End Class
```

Comment: I checked these and they both has `Public` modifier.